# rpm -e uninstall does not remove installed directory

Tags: rpm

So I have created a rpm package using a spec file and the installation is successful.
during the first time install, the rpm creates some basic directories 
say like

```
/userx/opt/myproj/bin/<binfile>
/userx/etc/opt/myproj
/userx/var/opt/myproj
```

When i try to uninstall from this location : `/userx/opt/`

```
rpm -e rpmname
```

the folder `myproj` is not removed but its contents are removed

but if i try to uninstall from any other location like `/userx` or `/tmp`
the folder `myproj` is removed and the contents are also gone.

is there any limitation the rpm -e command cannot be given at the location where the rpm executable folder is located ?

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right. If you were *in* `/userx/opt/myproj` on the other hand I could see it looking like the directory wasn't removed (in your prompt/etc.) until you used `cd` to move somewhere else but that's a different thing. Are you sure that's the only difference and that's exactly what is happening? What does rpm say it is doing for the removals if you bump debugging up to 10 (`-d 10`) on each attempt?

Comment: oh i did nt see any errors, i will try using this debug option. Thanks